# Dynamic allocation in C - Allocate into a function

Tags: c, malloc

What I want exactly is to allocate tab and fill it with some numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void prepare_internship(int** tab) {
    *tab = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    *(*tab+0) = 1;
}

int main() {
    int** tab;
    prepare_internship(tab);
    printf("%d", *(tab));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `But i get a memory problem` what exactly?

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Program has stopped working - Sourav Ghosh

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: At which line does it crash when you step through the program in your debugger?

Comment: `objects = (object**) malloc(...`  :  this can't change caller side `objects`.

Comment: Ah not that bug again. We had that yesterday too, was also a pointer-to-pointer passed by parameter. Methinks we need a canonical duplicate for this seemingly frequent bug.

Comment: `int** tab; prepare_internship(tab);` --> `int* tab;  prepare_internship(&tab);`

Comment: BLUEPIXY - i want an array of numbers not just one !

Comment: `tab[0],tab[1],tab[2],tab[3],tab[4]` you have them at main.

Comment: @XPRO An array of pointers is not an array of numbers, nor is it a 2D array of numbers.

Comment: Ok the question doesn't make any sense any longer after the radical edit...

Answer (score 3):

You're passing an uninitialized pointer into `prepare_internship`. What you need instead if you want the function to modify `tab` is:

```
int* tab;
prepare_internship(&tab);
```

But in this case it's better to change your function to have a `int*` return type and then you can simply call it with `tab = prepare_internship();`

Comment: I need to take speed typing lessons.  ;-)

Comment: hhh Thank you too ☺ but i still don't understand why I should pass an initialized pointer !

Comment: @XPRO You need to pass in the address of an actual variable that you want the function to change. What your code did was pass in an uninitialized address that points to a random memory position.

Answer (score 0):

`int** tab` is not initialized.  It should be `int* tab` and when passed as an argument, passed like this:  `&tab`.